# Shape manipulation of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

The 'd' is given condition however it was obtained.
I want to get 'result' in the required shape.
I tried it as follows; but it's beyond my imagination.

```
import numpy as np
data = [np.ones((300,1)), np.ones((300,5)), np.ones((300,3))]

result = []
for d in data:
  **print np.shape(np.array(d))**
  result.append(d)
print np.shape(np.array(result))
```

The result should be in this shape:
`(300, 1+5+3) = (300,9)`

Can someone help me?

I got

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (300,1) into shape (300)

EDIT:
data is just to make this question; it is just representation of my large program. given condition is `d`, which is a list but different shapes are list are generating from the for loop.

Comment: What do you actually get?

Comment: Also, you do realize that your loop just recreates the original array?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I got `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (300,1) into shape (300)`

Comment: Try `concatenate`on the first axis.

Comment: @jean. Post that in your question. It is not complete without the actual result.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have edited!

Comment: @hpaulj I could not figure out how to do that.

Comment: @jean. And I have retracted close vote! Thanks. What version of numpy?

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks it is 1.9.2 Python 2.7 64 bit.

Comment: OK. I was working with an older version that gave a different error message. Fixed now.

Comment: Please provide insight or give an example of what `d` is expected to be.  Everyone who has answered your question is now left with more questions than answers.  Please take the time to either reformulate your question or add more information to your problem so that we don't needlessly provide you solutions that don't work for your problem.  It's both frustrating for us, as well as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 2d arrays the differ in the last dimension can be joined on that dimension

```
Np.concatenate(data, axis=1)
```

`hstack` does the same.

In my comment I suggested axis 0, but that was a quick response and I didn't a chance test it.

When you try ideas and they fail, show us what was wrong.  You list a `ValueError` but don't show where that occurred.  What operation.

Your comments make a big deal about `d`, but you don't show how `d` might differ from the elements of `data`.

Comment: In my real problem, the d is obtained through long processing which has to be converted into result.

Comment: Concatenate `result`

Comment: I have added `print np.shape(np.array(d))`

Answer (score 2):

Your `result` is a Python `list`. In fact it is a `list` with the exact same contents as the original `data`. You are trying to concatenate arrays horizontally (along the second dimension), so you need to use [`numpy.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
import numpy as np
data = []
for d in some_source:
    data.append(d)
result = np.hstack(data)
print result.shape
```

If `some_source` is a list, a generator, or any other iterable, you can do this even more concisely:

```
result = np.hstack(some_source)
```

Comment: Sorry, data is not given; only d is given. I wrote `data` just as an example.

Comment: @jean, What does that mean? Do you only have one array?

Comment: In my real problem, the `d` is obtained through long processing which has to be converted into `result`.

Comment: @jean. I think that you should be a little more explicit about your real problem in the actual question. If you have to leave this many comments to explain what you really meant because everyone is reading your question the same way, you should consider the possibility that you are asking something other than what you intended.

Comment: `The `d' is so simple a list generated from for loop processing; but the problem is different shapes of `d` are generated from different for loops. You see that d are (300,1), (300,5), (300,3) shapes. All have to appended into required shape that is (300,9).`

Comment: @jean That is exactly what this code does. `hstack` takes an iterable (such as a list) of different sized numpy arrays and makes them into one big array along the second dimension. What's tripping you up?

Comment: `data` is just to make this question it is just representation of my large program. you just think `d`. please think that you do not know `data`, you know just `d`.

Comment: From 3 `d`s how you get the `result` of shape (300,9)?

Comment: Then rephrase your question. I have to have some source for `d`. It has to be the elements of a list or a generator or something. If your program is not doing so already, have it put stuff into a list.

Comment: Would you be happier if I wrote `data = [d1, d2, d3]`? I think that we all understand that `np.ones(..)` is a placeholder...

Comment: That is not what your question says. Fix your question and I will fix my answer.

Comment: @jean. That was pointless. You did not explain yourself at all and made it so the code does not run in an interpreter now. Your question should not have `data` anywhere in it if it is not part of the question. I have nevertheless modified my answer.

Comment: You should consider learning some of the fundamentals of Python generators and iteration. It seems that that is what is confusing you the most. My answer and @TillHoffman's were perfectly adequate for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [`numpy.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html), which essentially does `numpy.concatenate` under the hood.

## Example use

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: data = [np.ones((300,1)), np.ones((300,5)), np.ones((300,3))]

In [3]: out = np.column_stack(data)

In [4]: out.shape
Out[4]: (300, 9)
```

Comment: In my real problem, the d is obtained through long processing which has to be converted into result.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense.  Is your result a list of `numpy` arrays or what?

Comment: @jean Ok, so are you saying that you perhaps have an infinite loop and `d` is continuously being obtained?

Comment: yes around 10 times. I have to append all them into required shape.

Comment: @jean Why don't you just simply create a list of numpy arrays, then when you're done processing use `column_stack`, `hstack`, `concatenate`, etc.... basically any of the answers seen above?  You know that there is a limit on how many times the loop iterates, so why don't you just collect everything into a list, then use the list to get the final result?

Answer (score 1):

You want to stack the elements horizontally (if you imagine each element as a matrix with 300 rows and variable number of columns), i.e.

```
import numpy as np
data = [np.ones((300,1)), np.ones((300,5)), np.ones((300,3))]
result = np.hstack(data)
```

If you only have access to an iterator that generates elements `d` you can achieve the same as follows:

```
result = np.hstack([d for d in some_iterator_that_generates_your_ds])
```

Comment: Sorry, `data` is not given; only `d` is given.

Comment: @jean, What does that mean? Do you only have one array? Is `data` a generator or something?

Comment: In my real problem, the d is obtained through long processing which has to be converted into result.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import numpy as np
data = [np.ones((300,1)), np.ones((300,5)), np.ones((300,3))]

result = []
print(len(data))
for d in data:
    result.append(np.hstack(d))

print(result.shape)
```

This should do the job. You can also try:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.ones((300,1)), np.ones((300,5)), np.ones((300,3))

result = np.vstack(data[-1])

print(result.shape)
```

Both of which would yield `(300, 3)` as output.

If you're looking for `(300, 9)`, you can do as follows:

```
result = np.hstack(data)
```

Finally, if you'd like your results to be in `list()` as opposed to `numpy.array` or `numpy.matrix`, you can just stick a `.tolist()` to the end, like so: `result.tolist()`.